# Turn off accessibility service

Tags: root-access, bugs, accessibility

I have rooted my phone with KingRoot app, and suddenly "Ok Google" stopped working.

After a bit of searching I've found out that some accessibility services could been blocking it. And the only one on was KingRoot one. 
It is not a very useful service, so I turned it off, but in the next moment it has turned on again.

So my problem is, **does anyone knows how to permanently end this service?**, if not my question can be understood as, **anyone knows how to have ok google working with the service?**

I don't want to uninstall KingRoot, because I'm still working on the port to SuperSU, and it's not easy.

Comment: Kingo root is the worst rooting app. method... use something else

Comment: @SurendraPatil Can you read? Is KingRoot not kingo, and I don't like it either, but is the only one which works in my phone.

Comment: Have had very bad experience on samsung note 3, note 3 neo, S3, S5, lg G2and Htc mobiles... @Deltab   Which device do you use ?

Comment: @SurendraPatil LG Leon 4G version (H342f)

Comment: You can use the command line `pm disable <package/component>` to disable the accessibility service of that app. Alternatively, try [Elixir 2](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bartat.android.elixir). Install it -> launch it -> Applications -> locate your app -> tap it -> View Details -> scroll to Services -> disable its Accessibility service. Let us know the result.

Comment: @Firelord I'm used the command line, it disables the service, but also the app, don't know if I'm using it right. Gonna test the app later